# Where can I find the storage type (emmc, ufs, ssd, nvme) of an iPad online?

Tags: ipad

Where can I find the storage type (emmc, ufs, ssd, nvme) of an iPad online?

I thought I could find it easily online, but when I search something like: `ipad 2021 storage type`, `ipad 2021 specs`, `ipad 2021 memory type`, `ipad 2021 emmc`, `ipad 2021 ufs`, `ipad 2021 ssd` keywords, I can not find any useful results.

Can anyone show me the correct way to find the true ipad specs?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which iPad model? The latest models with M1 chips will have the same storage as described for the M1 Macs - it's NVMe SSD. But what will you do with the answer? It's a System on a chip - it is what it is.

Comment: @benwiggy I want to know how to find this kinda information online. I am not doing anything about it. I am trying to compare them and figure out which one I will buy. For now, I am trying to compare storage type for iPad 2021 (9th), iPad mini 6, iPad air4 etc.. All the 2021 editions. I don't know who downvotes my question. Is that not right to know which storage type I am going to buy for an iPad? I don't want to buy something blindly. Different people have different concerns. Some people concerns about the camera, but I am mostly concerning about the storage type. What's wrong with it?

Comment: There is a word count limit. So I have to write this second comment. Right now, I am comparing 2021 editions, but I will compare 2022, 2023 editions in the future. I just want to know how to find this information. Because when I buy a hardawre, I only conern about RAM, CPU and Storage Type. That's all. I don't care about other things. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't really a choice to be made. Models with newer SoCs will certainly be faster than older ones. So it's M1 > A15 > A14. That's it.

Comment: @benwiggy Why is there no choice? I'll compare the storage types and figure out which one I will buy. Eg: If a product uses eMMC and another one is using UFS, I will buy UFS one. If both products use UFS, I'll buy the cheaper one. Just exmaples. When I know what storage types they have, I'll decide which one I'll buy. It's not necessary to buy the fatest one. The order you posted is for the chip. I want to know the storage type. I will judge the storage type and the price and other specs all together. Right now, the storage type is one of most important part I have no ideas how to find.

Comment: @benwiggy I don't know why I don't make myself clear and you think there is no choice. You said ipad with M1 is using NVME SSD. If ipad 2021 with A13 is using NVME SSD too, I will simply buy ipad 2021 with A13. Because they have both NVME SSD, that will be enough to me. Something like this. Hopeffully, I make myself clear now. Storage type is one of most important specs that I buy devices. Btw, even if M1 SSD is faster than A13 with SSD, I don't really care about this, As long as they both are using NVME SSD. They won't make extremely different, comparing eMMC to NVME SSD in 2022.

Comment: Please edit the question with relevant details, they easily get lost in the comments.

Comment: The information here about "one chip" is false. The data storage on the iPad is not located "inside" the M1 somehow. It is just regular flash memory like older iPads.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for your kind reminder, But the comments are not my question. My question is just about the storage type of iPads. That's all. The comments are all things people want to know why I want to know the storage type. The reason why I want to know the storage type is not part of my question actually from my point of view. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not advertise the exact type of storage used. I guess because it is a technical detail that they do not require users to know about, and also because it is inherently difficult to compare as a "spec item".

You can also see this in your question, as you have confused and mixed together various terms - which makes comparison pointless. You list various storage types as "emmc, hfs, ssd, nvme" - which doesn't make any sense.

SSD means "solid state storage", which means storing data without having any moving mechanical parts. This is typically a form of "flash memory", as opposed to traditional hard drives that have rotating platters.

eMMC is a specific standard for SSDs that require them to conform to a specific electric interface and a data transfer protocol. It is usually in the form of a chip that is soldered on to a PCB.

HFS is a file system developed by Apple, which hasn't really seen mainstream usage in many years. A file system is a way to organize bytes on a disk - it doesn't really matter if that disk is an SSD, a hard drive or something entirely different.

NVMe is a protocol specification for accessing storage. The storage is usually a form of SSD, but it could in theory be almost anything. The electrical interface can be many different things (and even non-electric - i.e. optical).

The items above are in four different categories of things. It doesn't make sense to compare them.

Now to the actual, modern iPads made by Apple in the last few years:

You'll find that all of them (and indeed any iPad ever made) has an SSD in some form. I.e. solid state storage.

None of them have eMMC storage.

None of them uses HFS.

None of them uses UFS.

In fact you'll find that Apple in general do not buy off-the-shelf complete drives. Instead they use raw flash storage chips with their own, proprietary storage controller. For the latest iPads such as the iPad Air 5th Gen, this controller is embedded within the main System-On-Chip (SoC).

For your comparison purposes, you can just assume that every iPad made by Apple in the last 5 years or so have the equivalent of NVMe storage. It might not be actual NVMe storage, but it is the comparable of that.

You ask how to search for this type of information. Google is ofcourse always a good place to start, but as you indicate, it does require a technical background to understand any results you get. You can go to places like iFixIt to read about their tear-downs of various iPad models to see how they are made - but again, it requires technical knowledge in order to be able to understand their material.

The best way forward for you I guess is to ask some place like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. `HFS` is just a typo, I mean `UFS` and have corrected the typo.